# I run a program and encountered segmentation fault(core dump) , i debug with the gdb, the program was crashed when running ui->setupUI()

Tags: c++

//My test program as following, I just want to operate the data member which    //inherited from the base class, but get the problem of "Segmentation fault (core dumped)

#include 
    using namespace std;

```
class Ui_MainWindow
{
 public:
   int frame;
   int a;
   void setupUI()
    {
     frame = 0;
     cout<<"In setupUI() frame is:"<<frame<<endl;
    }
};


class MainWindow:public Ui_MainWindow
{
 public:
   MainWindow()
    { 
    frame = 111;                //assign for the data member from the base class
    ui->setupUI();
    }
   ~MainWindow(){}
   void paintFrame();
 private:
   MainWindow *ui;
};


void MainWindow::paintFrame()  //I just want to operate the data member which    //inherited from the base class
  {
   frame = 5555;
   cout<<"In MainWindow::paintFrame()frame is:"<<frame<<endl;
  }


int main()
{
 MainWindow w;
 w.paintFrame();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ui` is never initialized in `MainWindow`'s constructor. It points to some random location in memory.